# Is this set an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-curves

Is the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ and algebraic set? Intuitively, I think the answer is no because it is not possible to use a polynomial to split an arbitrary complex number into its real and imaginary components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. If it were an algebraic set (the zero set of a polynomial), then since we're in $\mathbb{C}$, it would be the zero set of a set of polynomials in one variable. Now a polynomial in one variable (if it's non-zero) always has finite zeros. This means that any algebraic set in $\mathbb{C}$ that is not all $\mathbb{C}$ must be finite. Reciprocally, any finite set is easily seen to be an algebraic set. So no, your set cannot be algebraic.

**EDIT** On the other hand, if we're looking at $\mathbb{C}$ like $\mathbb{R}^2$, then it IS the zero set of the polynomial $x^2+y^2-1$. So it depends on if we're looking at complex polynomials in one variable or real polynomials in two variables.

Comment: Unless he meant over R, in which case it is.